# The ) is missing error in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports, report

When I try to run my report in the Crystal Report 11.5.0.313 I getting the error msg "The ) is missing " and it is pointing me out at the report Formula Workshop on the following code:

```
TrimRight (SQLcall('SELECT rest_name FROM micros.rest_def WHERE store_id = (select fem_getstoreid(*))')) + ' - ' +
TrimRight (SQLcall('SELECT location_name_1 FROM micros.rest_def WHERE store_id = (select fem_getstoreid(*))'));
```

I successfully used this report before but our server had been changed and the CR had to be reinstalled top newer version. Does anybody know if there is any error with the formula...?

Comment: What is SQLcall here? Is it any User defined function?

Comment: Where did you write the formula

Comment: Fixed some typos. Besides try to add some details like the nature of the SQLcall and contestualize more your question.

Comment: ...the formula is taken from the report in POS MICROS 3700. These reports were working just fine until the DB (MICROS) was updated to higher version. I assume that the reports should be compactible. I did not edit or modified the formula. I guess that the reports are not compactible?? That's bit odd...

Answer (score 0):

Additional detail about "SQLCALL" would be helpful, but, I'm not sure if your SQL query is correct?

`SELECT location_name_1
FROM micros.rest_def
WHERE store_id = (
        SELECT fem_getstoreid(*)
        )`

What object is `"fem_getstoreid"`? - The syntax in the where clause is not correct for a table or a view, and store procedures cannot be called using "select"

If the problem started when your database changed, I would start by looking at that "fem_getstoreid".
If it is a view, the proper syntax would be

`Select store_id 
from femgetstoreid`

Comment: i'll try to have a look at the syntax in the common reports in newer version of MICROS and then compare them with reports from previous version....